# Find all matched pattern with grep

Tags: bash, shell, grep

In txt1

```
S01A1P2
S01A1P5
S01A1P4
```

In txt2

```
data/train/wave/S01A1P3.mfc
data/train/wave/S01A1P7.mfc
data/train/wave/S01A1P8.mfc
data/train/wave/S01A1P1.mfc
data/train/wave/S01A1P5.mfc
data/train/wave/S01A1P6.mfc
data/train/wave/S01A1P2.mfc
data/train/wave/S01A1P4.mfc
```

Use `grep -f txt1 txt2` and result

```
data/train/wave/S01A1P4.mfc
```

But I want this result that find all pattern

```
data/train/wave/S01A1P5.mfc
data/train/wave/S01A1P2.mfc
data/train/wave/S01A1P4.mfc
```

What can I do?

Comment: Add output of `file txt1 txt2` to your question.

Comment: `grep -f txt1 txt2` works for me, matching 3 lines.

Comment: [txt1](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/100069389/Note/Grep/txt1) [txt2](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/100069389/Note/Grep/txt2)

Comment: It works well, On which operating system you are running this ?

Comment: I'm running on Ubuntu 15.04

Answer (score 3, accepted):

txt1 contains CRLF line terminators. Try this:

```
grep -f <(dos2unix <txt1) txt2
```

Comment: or use `grep -f <(tr -d '\r' <txt1) txt2`

Answer (score 0):

```
grep -f txt1 txt2
```

Works for me too.

But you can also try to do it the ugly way-

```
for i in `cat txt1`
do
grep "$i" txt2
done
```

Comment: The ugly way doesn't work for me too :( . Where is my problem?